# Parsing AWS CLI commands

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services, parsing, aws-cli

I want to parse the output of AWS CLI command

```
aws ec2 describe-transit-gateways
```

[image]

[image]

From the above, the output I want to get is the name of the transit gateway which is given as a tag example: `("Name": "dev-tgw")`

I am able to retrieve TGW ID and Transit Gateway Owner from the below script

```
result=`aws ec2 describe-transit-gateways --profile $acc`

  for tgw in $(echo "${result}" |jq -r '.TransitGateways[] | @base64'); do

    _jq() {

      echo ${tgw} | base64 --decode | jq -r ${1}

    }
    
    Tgw=$(_jq '.TransitGatewayId')
    Tgw_owner=$(_jq '.OwnerId')
    Tgw_name=$(_jq '.Tags.Name')

    echo "$acc.Name"
    echo "Transit_Gateway": "$Tgw"
    echo "TGW_Owner_ID": "$Tgw_owner"
    echo "TGW_name": "$Tgw_name"
```

But I am not able to retrieve the Name of the TGW using

```
 Tgw_name=$(_jq '.Tags.Name')
 echo "TGW_name": "$Tgw_name"
```

What am I missing or am I looping it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following version:

```
result=$(aws ec2 describe-transit-gateways --profile $acc)

for tgw in $(echo "${result}" | jq -r '.TransitGateways[] | @base64'); do

    _jq() {
      echo ${tgw} | base64 --decode | jq -r "${1}"
    }
    
    Tgw=$(_jq '.TransitGatewayId')
    Tgw_owner=$(_jq '.OwnerId')
    Tgw_name=$(_jq '.Tags[] | select(.Key == "Name").Value')
    
    echo "$acc.Name"
    echo "Transit_Gateway": "$Tgw"
    echo "TGW_Owner_ID": "$Tgw_owner"
    echo "TGW_name": "$Tgw_name"
    
done
```

Comment: ```
jq: error: Could not open file |: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file select(.Key: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file ==: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file "Name").Value: No such file or directory

Comment: @Balakrishna did you copy exactly all code, not only one line of it?

Comment: @Balakrishna No problem. Glad it worked out:-)